# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]. Testing router+res.render functions with Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, routes, chai

My main.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';
const express = require( 'express' );
const app = express();
const homeController = require( './controllers/homeController' );
const errorController = require( './controllers/errorController')

console.log("+get homeController");
app.get( '/', homeController );

console.log('+get  homeController.showUsers');
app.get( '/users', homeController.showUsers );
```

In homeController.js there is this router.get method I want to test with Chai:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Internship Approval System'
  });
});
... 
module.exports = router;
```

My router.test.js file looks like this:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var router = require('./controllers/homeController');

describe('home route', function() {
  it('should return rendered response', function() {
    var req = {};
    var res = {
      render: sinon.spy()
    };

    return router.get(req, res).then(function() {
      expect(res.render.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

I'm getting an error when trying to see if it's called once:

```
  1) home route
       should return a rendered response:
     Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
      at Route.<computed> [as get] (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)

      at Function.proto.<computed> [as get] (node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
      at Context.<anonymous> (router.test.js:15:19)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

How can I modify `app.get( '/', homeController );` in main to contain a callback fucntion?

Answer (score 0):

homeController.js

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Internship Approval System'
  });
});

----

// Add this line in controller
module.exports = router;
```

---

main.js

```
// replace this
app.get( '/', homeController );

// like so
app.use('/', homeController);
```

Comment: Sorry i shouldve noted I had ```module.exports = router;``` in homeController, the app.use did not change the error

Comment: try with a different response like so `res.send('test')`, before `res.render` and see if i the error goes away

Comment: some other route is being matched then, debug your app or you could just do `console.log()` inside routes and see which one is getting matched, the way you did your `console.log()` in `main.js` that won't work it will only get executed once when you start the server

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("/users", () => {
  it("it should route to /users properly", done => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get("/users")
      .end((errors, res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(errors).to.be.equal(null);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

seems to work